# How to run BitTorrent Sync web browser gui via ssl

Tags: server, sync, bittorrent, ssl, https

I have installed BitTorrent Sync on my Ubuntu server, but noticed that the web gui does not use ssl for login (`https://server:8888/gui` does not work, however `http://server:8888/gui` does). This is both for logging in and using the gui while logged in.

Is there any way to force it to use ssl instead?

Comment: Will try to follow [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/) to achive this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Easy way

Use `btsync` configuration to achieve this, see `./btsync --dump-sample-config` configuration keys "force_https", "ssl_certificate", "ssl_private_key".

Even this seems simpler, I don't like that `btsync` user has access to certificate files. That's why I still prefer the next method.

## Hard way

I found the solution in [cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/) using nginx as proxy server. Successfully installed and configured on my ubuntu server installation.

Further steps assume that you have created SSL certificates in directory `/etc/nginx/certs/` (`ssl.crt` and `ssl.key`).

### Install `nginx`

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

### (Optional) Deactivate default configuration

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

### Create proxy configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy` with contents

```
server {
    ### server port and name ###
    listen          443;
    ssl             on;
    server_name     your-server-name.com;

    ### SSL log files ###
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/ssl-access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/ssl-error.log;

    ### SSL cert files ###
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/ssl.key;

    ### Add SSL specific settings here ###

    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    ### We want full access to SSL via backend ###
    location / {
            proxy_pass  http://{destination-host}:{destination-port};

            ### force timeouts if one of backend is died ##
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

            ### Set headers ####
            proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            ### Most PHP, Python, Rails, Java App can use this header ###
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;##
            #This is better##
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header              Front-End-Https   on;


            ### By default we don't want to redirect it ####
            proxy_redirect     off;
  }

}
```

Change values `your-server-name.com`, `{destination-host}`, `{destination-port}` and other values accordingly.

### Enable the configuration

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy
```

### Restart `nginx`

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Thank you! And I do agree - giving btsync access to the key isn't too nice...

Comment: The proper way would be to have the sync GUI listen on localhost:8888. With this proxy config the web GUI will still be available encrypted on port 8888.

Comment: You mean "the web GUI will still be available **not** encrypted on port 8888"?